# Error when Populating values for ComboBox.List

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm trying to populate a combo box with **UNIQUE** values only, no duplicates; which I believe is working fine, but something is wrong with my logic in the second `For` loop

The below logic goings as follows...

```
Private Function PopulateComboBoxWeeks()

   Dim i As Long
   Dim x As Long
   Dim LR As Long
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim SearchNextWeek As String

   LR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   Set ws = ActiveSheet

   With UserForm1.ComboBox1

      ''' Fill first slot in ComboBox1 with the value of last row in Column "A"
      .AddItem ws.Range("A" & LR).Value

      ''' Loop to search Column "A" for items to fill with, start on the second last row, since the above line fills the first line
      For i = LR - 1 To 2 Step -1

         ''' Loop to search the ComboBox.List() array
         For x = 0 To .ListCount
            ''' Array list starts at 0
            If Not (.List(x) = ws.Range("A" & i).Value) Then
               .AddItem ws.Range("A" & i).Value
            End If

         Next x

      Next i

   End With

End Function
```

It's checking the Array list properly, but I'm stuck on the second `For` loop, if I start at index `0` of my array and it's taking into account the total items in the array with `.ListCount`. Thus it's giving me the below error...

> **Run-Time error '381':**
>
> Could not get the List property. Invalid property array index

Which could only mean I'm referencing an array item outside of the array size. I've tried doing `.ListCount - 1` but this gives me an infinite loop. I think all my logic is sound here except this one item and I'm not sure how to get passed this point.

Comment: Nested loops? You're over-complicating this. You can assign `ComboBox1.List` to an array directly.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Wouldn't I still have to do the same thing? I will need to fill the array with unique values. Why not skip that step and place them directly into the `Combox1.List` array?

Comment: It separates two distinct concerns: 1) figuring out what the unique values are, and 2) setting the combobox list of available values. It also avoids the O(n^2) algorithm you have here and makes it O(n) for figuring out the unique values, and O(1) for populating the combobox, which should perform quite better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating any collection as you're changing it is always a bad idea.

Don't loop on anything. Just tell it what range you want to use.

If you can't do that, then you need to first get the unique values into an array (single-dimensional), then assign `ComboBox1.List = theArray`. Done.

There are two things you want to do:

1. Figure out what the unique values are
2. Assign the `List` property

Don't do these two things in one single nested spaghetti loop. Separate them.

```
Dim allValues As Variant
'get a single-dimensional array with all the values in the column:
allValues = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Range("A2:A" & LR).Value)

'let's use built-in collection keys to ensure uniqueness:
Dim uniqueValuesColl As Collection
Set uniqueValuesColl = New Collection

Dim currentIndex As Long
For currentIndex = LBound(allValues) To UBound(allValues)
    If Not IsError(allValues(currentIndex)) Then
        On Error Resume Next
        uniqueValuesColl.Add allValues(currentIndex), Key:=CStr(allValues(currentIndex))
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            ' we already have that value
            Err.Clear
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
Next

'now we know what the unique values are - get them into an array:
ReDim uniqueValues(0 To uniqueValuesColl.Count - 1)
Dim currentItem As Variant
currentIndex = 0
For Each currentItem In uniqueValuesColl
    uniqueValues(currentIndex) = currentItem
    currentIndex = currentIndex + 1
Next

'just assign the list of unique values
ComboBox1.List = uniqueValues
```

So I'm iterating all values once, and then the unique values once. But you're currently iterating them *once for every single item in the non-unique list*. So this solution is *O(n+m)* where *n* is the number of non-unique items and *m* is the number of unique items, whereas your nested loop is *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* (the big-O notation of your solution is actually more complicated than that, but I'm no big-O expert).

Comment: Wow... I'm very impressed, this worked perfectly. I've obviously got a lot to learn here. A lot of this code really doesn't make much sense to me, but I suppose I should do some more research

Comment: @Maldred if you could use an actual `Range`, you could even use `Range.RemoveDuplicates` and have Excel to the looping job (much faster than anything you could do in VBA), and then copy the resulting range into a 1D array, and poof you have your unique values without any loops! Curious, which part(s) are confusing?

Comment: Well I've never worked with `Collection`s before and what exactly is `ReDim`?

Comment: `Collection` is best used for objects, but can be used for anything really - it's just *usually* more efficient to use arrays. `ReDim` is an executable statement used for declaring a dynamically-sized array - you can't use `Dim` for that, because `Dim` statements aren't executable, so the code won't compile if you try to use expressions in it. `ReDim` can also be used for *re-dimensioning* arrays, optionally preserving the existing items (e.g. `ReDim Preserve foo(1 To X)`) - note that one should avoid resizing arrays in a loop, for efficiency reasons.

Comment: This is great information, more I can add to my knowledge! Thanks for all your help Mat, very fast and efficient code too :)

Comment: Note that you could alternatively add the items one by one in the `For Each` loop, but making it a habit of assigning the `List` to an array will make it trivial to adapt it to use e.g. a 2D array to populate a 2-column dropdown, which can't be done when adding items with `AddItem`.